# Which pattern (regex) should I use for splitting a litte text using ':' character as separator?

Tags: regex

I need to split a text onto two strings **using RegEx** (I can not use anyother method).

I have a text like:

```
This text should be first string: This text should be second string
```

I need to split the above text onto two string by character ':'. Trying achieve that I have use next pattern `[^:]*` but this is not working. I have tryed another patterns but nothing works.

Any idea which pattern should be the appropiate?

Thank you.

Comment: You can't really manipulate a string using regex alone, without an accompanying tool or programming language.  How are you using regex?

Comment: I am using GROK filter inside LogStash (ELK stack)

Comment: Try `^(?<val1>[^:]+):(?<val2>[^:]+)$`

Comment: Besides, have you tried the [Csv filter plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-csv.html)?

Comment: No, I did not try it, I will see this plugin. I'm happy to communicate your propossed pattern is working!! More specific, working pattern is: `(?<val1>[^:]+):(?<val2>[^:]+)`. Please, post it as a response and I will accept it charmed. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The straightforward regex is:

```
([^:]*):([^:]*)
```

Access the two parts / strings with `\1` and `\2`.

Test it [**here**](https://regex101.com/r/2e2pOU/1).